# Interpreting this command

Tags: linux, command-line, symlink

A few days ago I found the following command:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S ; do ln -s /etc/rc$i.d /etc/rc.d/rc$i.d ; done
```

As far as understand this command is going to create a symbolic link between each file using the for cycle, but **what I can't really understand is the S in that numeration, what is it supposed to do?**

Comment: It's an S. Much like the one at the end of my previous sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers aren't randomly selected, they're the [runlevels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Unix) of your system. The runlevel used to determine which init scripts are run. They're mostly obsolete now. And if you're on Linux, it's highly likely that the runlevels [S and 1 are the same](https://wiki.debian.org/RunLevel). Your documents might be really old, or they'd probably be using `update-rc.d` instead of manually creating symlinks.

So your loop is iterating over all runlevels, 1-6 and S.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly this is creating a symlink to the each of the initialization scripts?  Now this really makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @spurdosparde yes. But if you're on popular Linux distros like Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, CentOS, this is just supported for backwards compatibility, so there's not much to be gained from digging too much into it.

Answer (score 0):

All items after the 'in' in the for loop are strings that will be assigned to $i in the loop. The script will create soft links from /etc/rc?.d into /etc/rc.d/rc?.d. This is probably a bit of a hack to ensure some sort of compatibility between distros.

S is sometimes used as a synonym to runlevel 1 or single-user mode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel